# Why Walt Disney renamed Zootopia in UK?

Tags: title, alternate-version, zootopia

Why Walt Disney renamed "Zootopia" as "Zootropolis" in Uk? http://movies.disney.co.uk/zootropolis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.irishtimes.com/blogs/screenwriter/2016/03/10/why-is-zootopia-called-zootropolis-here/), there was no official reason except for some PR fluff ("In the UK we decided to change the US title to Zootropolis to merely allow the film to have a unique title that works for UK audiences"). But the feeling is that a zoo/safari park opening in Scandinavia called Zootopia might have had a claim on the copyright of any merch labelled as such.